# I have an app with react as frontend and django rest framework as backend, i use axios to send my response, but the data is empty

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios, django-allauth

I have an app with react and Django rest framework. I use Django allauth for login and registration. when I want to log in, everything is ok, and the response is 201 but the data is empty and I don't get token. I send this request with the postman and I get the token. what should i do?

React Request:

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/login/',
  data: {
    username: 'admin',
    email: '',
    password: 'admin123456'
  },
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data.key);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

the response is:

`{data: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}`

postman request: `http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/login/`

```
{
    "username": "mahtab",
    "email": "",
    "password": "mahtab23"
}
```

postman response:

```
{
    "key": "f75b9f54848a94ac04f455321118aff5d5a7e6f8"
}
```

Comment: Do you have the code for the React and Postman? Have checked that these are doing exactly the same thing?

Comment: yes, i think both of them behave same.

Comment: Please post some code so we can help.  As of right now what it sounds like is you could be using different HTTP methods, like a PUT in one and a GET in another.  You could be building the Axios request wrong.  It's hard to say without seeing anything.

Comment: Have you tried with same credentials? If so, have you checked the request from the browser is correct? Under Right Click `Inspect`.

Comment: Also, have you checked to make sure you aren't running into CSRF errors?  I know for Node.js if you are making requests from localhost to another localhost API that you are running it actually won't run the request for security purposes without doing a bit of modifying

Comment: @MichaelPlatt I used CSRF google chrome extension, but i have a  warning after the request. i think is not the problem with request, because i get 201 response. but maybe there is problem with CSRF.

Comment: What does the warning say?  Is there a meaningful message that could be a clue to the problem?

Comment: @MichaelPlatt xhr.js:178 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/login/ with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Comment: So that error makes it sound like you don't have doing CORS requests enabled.  If you are on Chrome, you can download https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en  Disable and re-enable it to make sure it is actually on and give it a shot